SSRS - Unable to use "As the user viewing the report" for Data sources
Environment Description:

SharePoint Subscription Edition
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 + SSRS installed

We have a site collection created, one of the feature is to use SSRS to generate report which consists of data from a few SharePoint Lists.
However, during our test, it is found that we can only setup a data source using option "Using the follolwing credentials" and the account inputted into this option was an admin account. This is not something we will use in production.
Whenever we try to test data source using credential option "As the user viewing the report", we will receive following error.

The connection string is correct as the same connection string works whenever Credential option "Using the following credentials" is selected.
In the reporting server log, we found below.
    dataextension!ReportServer_0-1!3308!10/31/2024-15:37:49:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPDPException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPDPException: An error occurred when accessing the specified SharePoint list. The connection string might not be valid. Verify that the connection string is correct.  ---> System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPListService.GetListCollection()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPRemoteConnection.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetLists>b__0(SPListService listSvc)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPRemoteConnection.ExecuteServiceRequest(ServiceRequest request)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;

We tested this when setting up data source using the SharePoint admin account
We also followed Microsoft's information in setting up our environment, but no luck, our environment is using NLTM.
Reference: Microsoft - Configure Windows authentication on the report server

Anyone encountered this issue and managed to resolve it?
